# Can I do a mulitvariate regression with the segmented package in r?

Tags: r, piecewise

I have FINALLY figured out how to use the segmented package with a uni-variate analysis giving results comparable to what I was expecting.  Ultimately though, I have to do a GLM piece-wise regression on a multivariate analysis.  The model has some variables that need to be segmented and some that do not as well as categorical variables.  Is this possible with the segmented package?

If so, how?

Do I have to keep interactively keep developing models adding one variable to the segmented package at at time?

```
piecewise <- glm(y ~ x, family = quasipoisson(link = "log"), data = data)  
piecewise_seg <- segmented(piecewise, seg.z = ~ x1, psi = 3) 
piecewise_seg2 <- segmented(piecewise_seg, seg.z = ~x2 psi = 400)
```

Or can I do this in one go?  If so, how can I set the different psi parameters for each different variable?

Comment: It's more likely that we will be able to help you if you provide [a complete minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to go along with your question. Something we can work from and use to show you how it might be possible to answer your question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @EricFail.  I found the answer towards the end of documentation of the segmented package.  See below.

Comment: I suggest you follow @Roland's advice below.

Answer (score 0):

Wait, I think I found it towards the end of the package documentation.

## 2 segmented variables: starting values requested via a named list

```
o1<-update(o,seg.Z=~x+z,psi=list(x=c(30,60),z=.3))
```

Comment: I suggest you delete your question since it could be solved by reading the documentation carefully.